# How to get `let` statement work on major three browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Firefox [requires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) using `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">` to activate ES6 `let` statement support.

> Note: The let keyword is only available to code blocks in HTML wrapped in a <script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"> block (or higher version). XUL script tags have access to these features without needing this special block.

However, it seems that this actually deactivates the whole script on both Internet Explorer and Chrome, as their debuggers do not show the script anymore.

Example: http://embed.plnkr.co/7YvyDZfPRsijqrHJnhMf/preview

<del>Is there any way to use `application/javascript;version=1.7` on IE/Chrome, or to use ES6 `let` on Firefox without the `type` attribute?</del>

Is there any hack to activate `let` statement support for all major browsers, while their implementations are not 100% standard-compliant?

Answer (score 5):

You are asking the wrong question. You should not ask when `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">` becomes available in other browsers, but when Firefox (and other browsers) will ship the [`let` keyword as defined by the ECMAScript 6 standard](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations). "JS 1.7" is a non-standard Firefox-only thing, and `let` in Firefox is slightly different from ES6's `let` keyword.

To know when `let` (and `const`, and block scope) is ready, just follow the following issues:

- Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=950547
- Chrome 41+ (Opera 28?): https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2198
- Internet Explorer 11+: https://status.modern.ie/blockbindingsletconstfunction ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/dn263046))

Comment: You're right, I didn't thought that `version=1.7` thing is non-standard thing. Thank you for fixing my question :)

Answer (score 0):

While we await the standard support of Firefox to the ES6 let keyword, you might want to *dynamically load the script* based on the type of browser you have using your server-side code (if you happen to be implementing a server-side web framework)

You might want to check the user agent string in order to detect the browser:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx